# Getting WordPress Blog feed to asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wordpress, rss

I don't know is it possible or not. I have my website in asp.net(VB). And my blog is in WordPress. I want my last 3 blog post to display to my asp.net website? Is it possible? If yes then guide me or suggest me a referral link

Comment: If you use wordpress.com you can use REST API https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/get/sites/%24site/posts/. If you have slef hosted WordPress blog then you need plugin, check this web site http://v2.wp-api.org/

Comment: @MatjažMav I have my own blog in wordpress in my hosting. Only concern is my website is in asp.net . So can I use this plugins?

Comment: Yes this [pluging](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/) is for your WordPress site. Node that it is still in beta. After you install this plugin you can use ASP.NET or even JavaScript to call API and get last few posts.